# How can I call javascript from template vue.js 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My view is like this :

```
...
 <td  @click="modalShow('modal-option', '{{ $i }}')">
    ...
</td>
...

@section('modal')
    <option-modal id="modal-option" :id="idModal"></option-modal>
@endsection
```

When the view clicked, it will display modal like this :

```
<template>
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                ...
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <a href="javascript:" class="text-danger" :id="'image-delete-' + id">
                        <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        name: 'OptionModal',
        props:['id'],
    }
</script>
```

I display modal with vue.js 2

When I click icon trash, I want to call javascript

I have global javascript. The name is main.js

The main.js is like this :

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
    $('#image-delete-'+i).click(function(){
        $('input[name="image-'+i+'"]').val('');
        document.getElementById("image-view-"+i).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("image-upload-"+i).style.display = "";
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
    });
}
```

When I clicked the trash icon in modal, javascript was unsuccessful called

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: why do u use interpolation inside the `@click` ? you get there full access to your methods and data.

Comment: You must $emit (raise) an event from option-modal and grab it on your view

Comment: @Max, I am confused. You should answer with the code

Comment: @LiranC, It does not matter

Comment: [Vue2 Events](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events)

Comment: When is your jQuery code that adds the click handler run? Is it in some function that gets passed `i`? When does that happen in relation to when the Vue is rendered?

Comment: @Bert Evans, When I click icon trash in modal vue.js. My jquery in loop. It Seems my question is clear enough

Comment: @TrendingNews I mean the code that *adds* the handler, not the handler itself. I suspect that you are adding the handler *before* the element with that `id` is rendered.

Comment: @Bert Evans, I am confused if read statement. You should answer with the code. So that I can easily understand

Comment: @TrendingNews show your complete main.js please.

Comment: @Bert Evans, Okay. I had update my question. The code like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the click handlers you are adding via jQuery will work depends *entirely* on *when* you add the click handlers. If you are adding the click handlers *before* the Vue is mounted, then your clicks will *never* fire.

**This won't work**

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
  $('#image-delete-'+i).click(function(){
    ...
  });
}

new Vue(...)
```

Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/pPXxBg?editors=1010).

If you add your handlers in `mounted`, then you can get it to work.

**This should work**

```
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
  },
  mounted(){
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
      $('#image-delete-'+i).click(function(){
        ...
      });
    }
  }
})
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/vmqQOv?editors=1010).

Finally, you *could* add your handlers in this fashion and it wouldn't matter *when* you added them.

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
  $(document).on("click", `#image-delete-${i}`, function(){
    ...
  });
}
```

But, I'm not sure this is what is happening because you give so little code. Of course the *ideal* case would be to let Vue define the handlers.

Comment: Okay, Thanks. I will try it first

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your help